# Custom perl installation cannot find Git.pm

Tags: perl, git, perl-module

I have installed my own copy of Perl in my home directory, but I have some Perl scripts that require Git.pm, which is part of the Git distribution and not installable from CPAN. The Git.pm used by the system perl resides at `/usr/share/perl5/Git.pm`. How can I make this Git.pm available to a custom perl install, or get another copy of Git.pm installed in the correct location? Should I just copy it into my own Perl's lib directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Git.pm` is self-contained, so copying it in a directory part of your private perl `@INC`. It requires `Error.pm` (with version greater or equal to 0.15009), so don't forget to install that module as well.

If you're looking for a Git wrapper (and not specifically Git.pm), there are several available on CPAN (in alphabetical order):

- `Git::Class`
- `Git::Repository`
- `Git::Wrapper`

Comment: I ended up simply copying the system copy of Git.pm into my own Perl's module directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the article [Perl modules FAQ - What to do when Perl modules aren't in their normal locations](http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010015), and add your module in the `@INC` variable path, by modifying directly your Perl script which needs `Git.pm`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/home/george/modules";
print "\@INC is @INC\n";
```

> use the `use lib` statement to add your search directory to Perl's search path.

Comment: But Git.pm is in the system Perl's module directory. I don't want to add all of the system Perl's modules to my custom installation, especially because some of those modules may be XS modules compiled for the system Perl that will die on my custom Perl.

Comment: @Ryan: can you move that module in a custom path, instead of leaving in the default (system) location?

Comment: Well, I can copy it. My current solution is to just copy the system Git.pm into my local installation at the appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

To control where Perl searches for modules, use `PERL5LIB` (or `PERLLIB`).

To have your module/script use some module at non-standard location, use `use lib "<dir>";` (thought I think it is *usually* deprecated).

To install Perl modules locally from CPAN, use `local::lib`.

Comment: Git.pm is not installable from CPAN, and I cannot add its current directory to `PERL5LIB`, since that would all *all* of the system Perl's modules to my custom Perl's path. Should I just copy Git.pm from the system Perl's directory into some random directory in my home and then add that to `PERL5LIB`?

Comment: @Ryan: if Git.pm is installed in system Perl's directory, how it is that your modules/scripts do not find it?  If you install Git.pm locally, you can always install it in "local::lib" place (i.e. `~/perl5` by default).

Comment: I am using my own copy of Perl, because I want the latest version but the system (Ubuntu Natty) only provides 5.10. So adding the system Perl's directories to PERL5LIB would be a bad idea.

Comment: @Ryan: How dod you install Git.pm (or how did you get it)?

Comment: Git.pm is installed as part of Git. On Ubuntu it is installed at `/usr/share/perl/Git.pm`, but many (all?) other system-installed Perl modules are also installed there as well.

Comment: @Ryan: So Git.pm is system-installed, but you use your copy of Perl (perlbrew?).  What you need is copy of Git.pm with your Perl: either straight copy, or install perl-Git package relocating it, or install Git.pm from git sources...