# git checkout --patch, but failed, Can't locate Git.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, git, perl, cpan

When I run git checkout --patch origin/master file.java, I see:

```
Can't locate Git.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Git module) 
(@INC contains: 
/usr/share/perl/5.14.2 
/usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/x86_64-linux 
/usr/local/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.0 
/usr/local/perl/lib/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/perl/lib/5.20.0 .) 
at /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive line 7.
```

I run it on the Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. The version of git is 1.7.9.5. The perl is perl5, version 20, subversion 0 (v5.20.0) build for x86_64-linux.

Comment: There should be `/usr/share/perl5/Git.pm` (from `git` package, verify its existance with `dpkg -L git | grep Git`) and `/usr/share/perl5` directory should be in the default perl5 search paths

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/6159854/6309 help?

Comment: I have solved the problem by using the method of user3159253. /usr/share/perl5/Git.m is existing, but the /usr/share/perl5 wasn't in the default perl search paths(using perl -V). Then I add export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5 into the ~/.bashrc. Then it works well. Thanks.

Comment: For those running into this issue on OS X, check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/17736330/72321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/share/perl5/Git.pm` (or similar, depending on the system) might be missing in `PATH`.

Adding `export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5` to `~/.bashrc` file should resolve the issue.